# Use tornado as a proxy, got a memory leak and don't know why?

Tags: memory-leaks, proxy, tornado

I want to use tornado to act as a proxy_server. The things are simple:
1. recieve request from some client
2. get url, param, headers from the request
3. use a proxy to make request with the things in 2
4. return response content, headers and the proxy to client
here's the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import functools
import base64
import sys

from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
import tornado.web

import util


AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient")

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):


    def handle_response(self, proxy, response):
        if response.error:
            self.write("error")
        else:
            headers = {name.lower(): value for name, value in response.headers.get_all()}
            result = {
                "content": base64.b64encode(response.body),
                "headers": headers,
                "proxy": proxy,
                }
            self.write(json.dumps(result))
        self.finish()


    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def post(self):
        url = self.get_argument("url", "")
        body = self.get_argument("body", "")
        headers = json.loads(self.get_argument("headers", ""))
        method = self.get_argument("method", "GET")
        proxy = self.get_argument("proxy", "")
        client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        if proxy == "":
            proxy = util.get_random_ip() # get a proxy string, like '118.150.101.160:18088'
        proxy_info = proxy.split(":")
        request_info = {
            "method": method,
            "headers": headers,
            "connect_timeout": 2,
            "request_timeout": 5,
            "proxy_host": proxy_info[0],
            "proxy_port": int(proxy_info[1]),
            }
        cf = functools.partial(self.handle_response, proxy)
        if method == "POST":
            request_info["body"] = body
        client.fetch(url, callback=cf, **request_info)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = sys.argv[1]
    print "start at port : ", port
    application = tornado.web.Application([(r"/proxy", MainHandler)])
    server = HTTPServer(application)
    server.listen(int(port))
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

when the requests growing to about 300 per min(5/s not too high), the memory start to goes wrong. I use "glances" to check system info, at the begining, the memory used is **16.6M**, but 3 min after, the memory raise to **107.8M**, 10 min latter, the number can up to **8518.6M**, that's horrible!

I don't know why, any help?